# How to call from background.js a content script that opens and dynamically creates a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a google chrome extension which shows notifications on specific circumstances, and when the notification is clicked I need to open a new tab using an html file which needs to be edited after an api call. The way I tried to do that is by injecting a content script in background.js but I can't get it to work. Is there any better/easier way to do it?

Background.js part of code

```
//chrome.sendMessage()
var myWindow=window.open ("index.html","mywindow");
var activeTabId;
chrome.tabs.getCurrent( function(tab){ activeTabId = tab.id } );
chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTabId, {"file": "contentScript.js"});

(contentScript.js code)

var myWindow=window.open ("index.html","mywindow");
var cards=myWindow.document.getElementById('cards');
console.log(cards);
let new_card = '<div class="col-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 p-0 mr-2 col"> <div class="card">  <a 
class="text-center" href=""> <div class=" f-16 text-dark mt-4 card-title"> <strong class="text- 
capitalize">NEW CARD</strong> </div> </a>  </div> </div> ';
cards.innerHTML=new_card;
```

Comment: Your index.html can't run content scripts because it's your own extension's page so just use a normal script like index.js and load it as `<script src="index.js">` in index.html. Then simply pass the data to that new window, [example](/a/54715122).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried something like that and it didn't work, but I will try it again and come back with a reply.Thank you.